# D3 Hexagon edges

Tags: d3.js

@drinck: Thanks a lot, you helped me big time.

I have 1 more question if you can check it... On the image you can see how i coded the situation and what i have and what is the desired hexagon.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb9y8.jpg

And my function for drawing the hexagons 1 over another

```
function drawHexa ($container) {
    var $cont = $($container);
    var contW = $cont.width();
    var contH = $cont.height();
    var color = $cont.data('color');
    var pointSrc = $cont.data('points');
    var pointData = [];

    $.ajax({
        url: pointSrc,
    }).done(function(response) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.points.length; i++) {
            pointData.push(response.points[i]);
        };

        var svgContainer = d3.select($container) //create container
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", contW)
            .attr("height", contH);

        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate('linear')
            .x(function(d,i) { return d[0];})
            .y(function(d) { return d[1];});

        var path = svgContainer.append('path')
            .attr('d', line(pointData))
            .attr('stroke', color)
            .attr('stroke-width', '22')
            .attr('fill', 'none');

        var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

        path
            .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
            .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
            .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .ease("linear")
            .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
    });

}
```

Do you think this can be done with d3 ?